# How to find of filter only the new data appearing in a data set but not in a previous set?

Tags: r

Given I have flowing data set.

```
a = 1:3
b = 1:3
df1 = expand.grid(a,b)
c = 1:5
d = 1:5
df2 = expand.grid(c,d)
df3 = rbind(df1,df2)
df4 = unique(df3)
```

The premise is that df1 has a set of parameters. df2 has the same parameters, but with an expanded set.
In the example df4 uses unique to remove any duplicated rows but it keeps only 1 of each of the duplicated rows, such that df4 is effectively the same as df2.

I need to completely remove the duplicated rows, not keep any unlike unique.

Basically I need a df5 that would only contain rows from df2 that are not part of df1, or completely remove all duplicated rows from my df3.

```
df5
   Var1 Var2

1     4    1
2     5    1
3     4    2
4     5    2
5     4    3
6     5    3
7     1    4
8     2    4
9     3    4
10    4    4
11    5    4
12    1    5
13    2    5
14    3    5
15    4    5
16    5    5
```

Comment: No, !duplicated is like unique. in the listed sample the 0 1 4 and 1 0 2 should also be removed leaving only 1 1 4 which is truly unique.

Comment: @Jaap it is closed now.

Comment: @akrun Thx for closing. This shows several things: (1) you agree that reopening this question wasn't justified; (2) you are able & willing to close questions; (3) complaining by you that 'nobody' wants to close a certain question actually means that you are blaming yourself for not closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df2, df1)
```

Or `setdiff` from `dplyr`

```
setdiff(df2, df1)
#   Var1 Var2
#1     4    1
#2     5    1
#3     4    2
#4     5    2
#5     4    3
#6     5    3
#7     1    4
#8     2    4
#9     3    4
#10    4    4
#11    5    4
#12    1    5
#13    2    5
#14    3    5
#15    4    5
#16    5    5
```

Or with `fsetdiff`

```
library(data.table)
fsetdiff(setDT(df2), setDT(df1))
```

Answer (score 1):

In dpylr, the following function should get you want you want:

```
 setdiff(df2,df1)
```

It is essentially a left excluding sql join